# OneSignal Wordpress Notifications not opening in App

Tags: wordpress, cordova, onesignal

I am struggeling to find a solution for my Cordova Native App.

I am using OneSignal to send out push notifications once a new Article has been published. The push notifications are working fine but the moment I click onto the notification the normal browser opens and not the app.

NB: When I send a test notification through OneSignal and click on it the App opens.
My code just does not want to work with Wordpress articles.

Here's the code which I am using in my index.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
  var additionalData = jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData
  if (additionalData && additionalData.myKey)
    // Not familiar with Cordova, $state may or may not be available here
    $state.go('app.post', {'postId': + additionalData.myKey});
};

  window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("0b8b7e69-1649-4616-XXXXXXX")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();

  // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your app if you have the user's email.
  // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail);
}, false);
```

Has anyone any idea what is possibly wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to put all codes under plugin check on device ready function and make sure you parse the data into array object because they sending raw looks like -

```
if (window.plugins && window.plugins.OneSignal) {
    .startInit(your_appid, your_google_project)
    .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
    .handleNotificationOpened(function(jsonData) {
        if (device.platform =="Android") {
            var addData = JSON.parse(jsonData.result.notification.payload.additionalData);
        } else {
            var addData = jsonData.result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        }
        if (addData != undefined) {
            if (addData.posts != undefined) {
                var postID = Number(addData.posts);
                $state.go('app.post', {postId: postID });
            }
        }
    })
    .endInit();
}
```

Note: According to there doc they update the additional data tree to

```
result.notification.payload.additionalData
```

Not `notification.payload.additionalData`

Put this function on your wordpress theme function.php and make sure you have disable the option "Send notifications additionally to iOS & Android platforms". on WordPress plugin page.

```
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $postID = $post->id;
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
       "posts" => $postID
   );
   return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. So I must leave the Android/iOS code as is and just disable notifications and then add the above code into my functions.php?

Comment: Hi. Just tested your code. Notification arrives delayed. And it does only open the App but not the respective article posted.

Comment: Can you post you debug log?

Comment: What is Your app os?

Comment: just tested it on android

Comment: And your plugin version? I found a soln will update my answer.

Comment: Okey and your plugin version.?

Comment: Your are using ionic?

Comment: No I am using Android Studio now. Plugin Version and Android Studio are up to date

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my ans, let me know still you are facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here, in case someone else can make use of it.

```
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notication_filter_push', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notication_filter_push($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    // overwrite http url with app_url so push notifications opens app instead of phone browser. 
    $fields['url'] = $fields['app_url'];

    return $fields;
}
```